# Connecting to SQL Server via Windows Authentication with Java providing credentials

Tags: java, sql-server, windows-authentication

I have a java application I am writing to help my department audit our documentation by comparing the data in the database to expected outcomes.  It also allows for the creation of reports to verify the data.  I have been able to get it to work perfectly but now my supervisor wants more people to be able to use the application than the Database Admin wants to grant access to.  So here is the problem:

I need to be able to connect to MS SQL Server (using Windows Authentication) by using different credentials (like a common username and password for all user of the application) than the windows user account.  Is there a way to manipulate or set the credentials that are sent to the server for Windows Authentication?  What driver should I be using or external jars should I attach?

The users are on the same Domain as the server so that should not be an issue.  I also do not need to know how to connect using Windows Authentication, I have already been doing that.  And I do not need SSO.  I looked into JTDS but it seems to be grabbing the windows account still using the following format:

```
String DATABASE_URL = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<ServerName>:<port>/<DatabaseName>;user=<username>;password=<password>;domain=<Domain>;";
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure this is unsupported.

> When a user connects through a Windows user account, SQL Server
>   validates the account name and password using the Windows principal
>   token in the operating system. This means that the user identity is
>   confirmed by Windows. SQL Server does not ask for the password, and
>   does not perform the identity validation. Windows Authentication is
>   the default authentication mode, and is much more secure than SQL
>   Server Authentication. Windows Authentication uses Kerberos security
>   protocol, provides password policy enforcement with regard to
>   complexity validation for strong passwords, provides support for
>   account lockout, and supports password expiration. A connection made
>   using Windows Authentication is sometimes called a trusted connection,
>   because SQL Server trusts the credentials provided by Windows.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx

Comment: When looking at jTDS it mentions being able to use windows authentication with non-Windows machines.  I would imagine that same process could be replicated from a Windows machine, but maybe I'm wrong.  [http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html](http://jtds.sourceforge.net/faq.html) says "Without the native SSO library installed you still have to provide the username and password because otherwise jTDS cannot determine user credentials. There is a good side to this: users on non-Windows platforms are able to log in using Windows credentials by providing them in the URL, along with the domain name."